# Adding Function on Sign Out button by php

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website where I want to sign in and sing out. So when I sign in I redirect to home.html, so in home.html I added a button by naming it "logout", I want to add function on it so whenever I will click on that button it will sign me out. As I know already, the code I have to use but don't know how put that code to logout button?
I want to know how I can refer my this button name="logout" button to that specific code 
session_destroy(); so when I m in home.html click on Sign out button it will destroy my current season and locate me back to index.php.
index.php

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="process.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="email" for="inputtext" class="col-sm-4 control-label">User name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="User name" name="username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label id="pass" for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Enter Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign me in!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

process.php

```html
<?php
     $action = $_GET['action']; 
     if ($action == 'logout') {
     unset($_SESSION['username']); 
     }
     
     
     
     $username = $_POST ['username'];
     $password = $_POST ['pass']; 
     
     //fixed values
     
     if($username=='syedhasan' AND $password=='Syed712207') {
     echo "You have successfully logged in"; 
      header('Location: home.html');   
     }
     
     else {
     echo "Credential is wrong";  
      
     }
      
     ?>
```

in home.html i have added this button

```html
<input href="logout.php" type="submit" class="signout btn btn-warning"" value="Sign Out" name="logout">
```

THen i created logout.php

```html
<?php
session_start(); 
unset($_SESSION); 
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: index.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: How does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Create another file named "logout.php".Place the below code.

```
<?php

session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");

?>
```

On click of "logout" button ,it should redirect to "logout.php".

Answer (score 0):

Just create another page called logout.php. Unset the session there unset($_SESSION['someusername']) and write code to redirect to your home page.

header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Answer (score 0):

I assume your login page is `login.php`, there I guess you have a html form for username and password, and also have the user validation with the redirect to home.html. It makes sense to put the logout logic also in there.

Put the following code to the top of `login.php`:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if($action == 'logout') {
  /* I'm sure you don't want to destroy the entire session, as there
     could be other valuable data stored, so use unset to destroy only 
     the specific login-variable. */
  unset($_SESSION['loginVar']);
}
```

`$_SESSION['loginVar']` is the session var where you users login data is stored.

Now you can use the following href for the logout link / button:

```
login.php?action=logout
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is give user a link to sign out, and redirect the page to index.php.

home.html:

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok 
you have logout buttom with  and you have to make logout.php and link it to logout buttom 
for example

logout.PHP

```
<?PHP 
session_start();
session_destory();
unset($_SESSION['user_id']); 
header("location: login.html");
?>
```

And index.html like this

```
<a name="logout" href="logout.php"> Logout </a>
```

Comment: I have added all my codes i have used to make that page, can you check it. I have followed what u said but still it is not working. Thank u

Comment: @HasanSyed Give your files or explain what you have completly

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<a href='index.php?logout=1'>Logout</a>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'))
{
   session_destroy();
   header('Location:home.php');
}
```